# L3 cache appears as disabled

Tags: cpu, cache

In my XPS 8700 i7 4790, the comand lshw shows that the 8MB L3 cache is disabled, does this mean that the L3 cache is not working? should I not use ubuntu and go back to windows? does the operating system differ? or is the cache operation is totally done in hardwarw? Also in the BIOS there is no option to disable/enable cache, and it only show info about the L1,L2,L3 caches. I am using ubuntu 14.04.

output of lshw

```
*-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 27
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through unified
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 29
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal write-through unified
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 2a
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
```

Output of lscpu

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               844.171
BogoMIPS:              7184.05
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Comment: Could you give the output of `lscpu`?

Comment: it just show the l3 size

Comment: If your L3 were disabled, you'd notice it, your computer would be really slow (there're bugs were a computer would take like an hour just to boot because of caching issues). In your `lscpu` looks like the kernel "detects" the L3 cache: **L3 cache: 8192K**. I suppose this should be a bug of `lshw` in detecting low-level caches of new series of CPU. You should not get worried as it may get fixed upstream.

Comment: Thanks, this  saved me a lot of time/effort as I was just going to install windows which I dont really like for my development pc.

Comment: Ok I add it as the answer so that others may notice if they concern the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your L3 were disabled, you'd notice it, your computer would be really slow (there're bugs where a computer would take like an hour just to boot because of caching issues). In your lscpu looks like the kernel "detects" the L3 cache: L3 cache: 8192K. I suppose this should be a bug of lshw in detecting low-level caches of new series of CPU. You should not get worried as it may get fixed upstream.